# Does an out-of-sight creature affected by the Fear spell have to keep running if they fail the saving throw?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, movement, line-of-sight, fear

Imagine a (D&D 5e) spellcaster casts *Fear* on an enemy, and the enemy fails their Wisdom saving throw. On its turn, the enemy drops what it's holding and takes the Dash action, running away from the spellcaster and around a corner, putting it out of sight of the spellcaster. The enemy ends its turn out-of-sight of the spellcaster, so it can make the Wisdom saving throw again; again, it fails.

On its next turn does the enemy have to *continue running away*? Even though it's out of sight of the spellcaster?

My reading of the spell is yes: they have to continue to run away until they succeed on the save (or the spellcaster drops the spell for some other reason).
Is this right? Or can the enemy remain in place out-of-sight?
(They obviously can't move closer to the spellcaster because they're affected by the frightened condition.)

Comment: Related: [What happens if you're frightened of a hidden or invisible creature?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/169009/52137), [Does the frightened condition provide supernatural knowledge of the location of the source of fear?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/124451/52137)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Yes.

First, the end condition of the [*fear*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fear) spell (PHB, pg. 239):

> If the creature ends its turn in a location where it doesn't have line of sight to you, the creature can make a Wisdom saving throw. On a successful save, the spell ends for that creature.

So when the creature can no longer see the caster, it may make the save. On a success the effect ends, on a failure, return to the beginning of the paragraph:

> While frightened by this spell, a creature must take the Dash action and move away from you by the safest available route on each of its turns, unless there is nowhere to move.

This is the effect of the spell, and this describes what you do until you succeed on the save.

[This answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/124457/62294) gives some insight into what this may look like in play. Essentially, you are compelled to move away from where you think the source of the fear is.

Comment: Cool; that reading agrees with mine, so I'll go with that.